# How to chain flux to another flux/mono and apply another back pressure?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have below reactive code using flux in reactor core:

```
Flux.create(sink -> ... /* listens to and receives from external source */ , FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST)
    .flatMap(map -> redisHashReactiveCommands.hmset(key, map))
    //.flatMap(... //want to store same data async into kafka with its own back pressure handling)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .doOnNext(s -> log.debug("Redis consumed. Result -> {}", s))
    .doOnComplete(() -> log.debug("On completed."))
    .doOnError(exception -> log.error("Error occurred while consuming message", exception))
    .subscribe();
```

As you can see, I have back pressure handling on this for external source to my process (FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST). However, I also want to configure back pressure for my process to redis (redisHashReactiveCommands.hmset(key, map)) since it can be a bigger bottleneck than external source to my process. I expect I'd need to create another flux for redis part and link it with this flux, but how do I achieve this since .flatMap works on individual item and not a stream of items?

Also, I want to store the same emitted item into Kafka as well but chaining flapMap's doesn't seem to work.. is there an easy way to link all these together in one set of functional calls (external source -> my process, my process -> redis, my process -> kafka)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not interested in the result objects *in the main sequence* you could combine both saves from within the `flatMap`. You'd have to move the subscribeOn and log inside the flatMap as well to put them on the inner save publishers:

```
Flux.create(sink -> ... /* listens to and receives from external source */ , FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST)
    .flatMap(map -> Mono.when(
        redisHashReactiveCommands.hmset(key, map)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .doOnNext(s -> log.debug("Redis consumed. Result -> {}", s)),

        kafkaReactiveCommand.something(map)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .doOnNext(s -> log.debug("Kafka consumed. Result -> {}", s)),
    ))
    //... this results in a Mono<Void>
    .doOnComplete(() -> log.debug("Both redis and kafka completed."))
    .doOnError(exception -> log.error("Error occurred while consuming message", exception))
    .subscribe();
```

Alternatively, if you're *sure* both processes emit either a result element or an error, you can combine both results into a `Tuple2` by replacing `when` with `zip`.

Comment: Thanks. I have a few questions regarding your answer:
1.Regarding use of ```Mono``` and  ```Schedulers.parallel()``` on inner publishers, does this actually process each emitted item sequentially or all items in parallel as they come in individually?
2.How to handle different back pressure for Kafka flow? Should I be using ```Flux.zip``` instead of ```Mono.when```(Reactor Kafka uses Flux)?  ```FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST``` is fine for both (external source -> my process) and (my process -> redis) but I want to use ```.window(100)``` for batch processing for (my process -> kafka) flow.

Comment: 1. It will effectively parallelize up to flatMap's default concurrency factor (256). 2. Maybe you then need 2 separate pipelines? Look at the share operator to be applied on create

Comment: I can't find any example on share().. do I just apply it on the main Flux?
Flux.create(sink -> ..., FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST)
    .share()
    .flatMap(map -> Mono.when(
        redisHashReactiveCommands.hmset(key, map)
    ....

Comment: You store `Flux.create(...).share()` in a variable `foo`. You then define 1 Flux pipeline for Redis out of `foo`, and one for Kafka (this one with `window(100)` and the like). You can also use `onBackPressure*` operators to tune the backpressure behavior, thus removing the need to deal with it at the `create` level.

Comment: Thanks.. one more question, how do I make the emitted items in inner flux (i.e. inside ```redisHashReactiveCommands.hmset(..)```) to be processed sequentially rather than in parallel (but still make it async rather than blocking call), as the order of processing is important? I assume there must be a way to specify single background thread to be used for processing all emitted items?

Comment: Use concatMap instead of flatMap (or flatMapSequential if you want to subscribe early yet maintain order)